# How to select a child element by its class name in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code, I need to write a simple function.
Passing a parent element (in my case menu-top) find out the element with class focus.

```
   <div id="menu-top">
        <ul>
        <li id="menu-top-item-0" class="item0 focus">1</li>
        <li id="menu-top-item-1" class="item1">2</li>
        <li id="menu-top-item-2" class="item2">3</li>
        <li id="menu-top-item-3" class="item3">v 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I am trying this with no success jquery 1.4.2

```
getFocusedElement: function(parentElm) {
    return $(parentElm).find("focus");    
}
```

any idea?

Comment: `$(parentElm).find(".focus")` will work. You should use selectors as in css.

Comment: You're missing the `.` (class selector). try `.find('.focus')`.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `.` in your class-selector, e.g.:

```
return $(parentElm).find(".focus");
```

Using `"focus"` as your selector will try to match to an element with the tag-name `<focus />`

Here's more info on how jQuery selectors work: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

`$(parentElm).find(".focus")` will work. JQuery takes css selectors for element selections.

I.e. classes will have a `.` prefix, and ids will have a `#` prefix.